# Incomplete Metric Space in R - Examples

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Which sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ do not converge with the metric d(x,y)=|$\frac{x}{1+|x|}-\frac{y}{1+|y|}$|?

I am struggling to think of a sequence to get the numerator to increase faster than the denominator to reach infinity, which is not included in the real line, but cannot think of anything. Am I thinking along the correct lines?

Comment: Considering the title of your question, I imagine that you want an example of a Cauchy sequence that doesn’t converge for this metric. If so, it would be good that you update accordingly your question.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence $(n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence for $d$ that doesn’t converge in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Is this because it is impossible to have $\frac{1}{1+|x|}=1$?

Comment: It is because if a sequence goes to $\infty$ for the usual distance it converges to $1$ for $d$.

Comment: Why could we not just say the limit point is 1 and the sequence converges then?

Comment: The limit point is not equal to $1$. If it was you would have $d(n,1) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ which is not. Don’t confuse the limit point of the sequence and the limit point of the distance of the sequence to the origin.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

First you must proof the claim that the Euclidean metric $| \cdot |$ is an equivalent metric with d. 
Next we consider the sequence $ x_n=n, \ n\in N$.  This sequence is d-Cauchy because $$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists n_0 , \forall m,n>n_0 : 1-\varepsilon /2<\frac{n}{n+1} <1+\varepsilon /2$$ and $$1-\varepsilon /2<\frac{m}{m+1} <1+\varepsilon /2. $$ Consequently, $d(x_n,x_m)<\varepsilon , \forall m,n>n_0$. But, this sequence is not d-convergent because if it was then from the previous claim the sequences would be $| \cdot |-$ convergent but as we know from calculus the sequence $x_n=n, n\in N$ does not converges (with respect to Euclidean metric).